# Change url without redirect in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular 2 web application I would like to change the url page in the browser. For example I'd like to change it from:

http://localhost:63000/my-page

to

http://localhost:63000/your-page

It must not redirect, no page load, and browser history must reflect the page change.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 12):

This can be achieved by below function available in angular 4

```
location.replaceState(path: string, query?: string): void;
```

Before doing this you need to get location object by injecting in your component or directive constructor.

```
  constructor(private location: Location)
```

And importing Location class like this -

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```