# Change url path without redirecting

Tags: angular, router

I have a page, which I would like to change the url (for coming to the same end point if the user copu/paste the url) but that doesn't need any redirect if the user don't refresh the page.

I tried to follow this     [Change url without redirect in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009262/change-url-without-redirect-in-angular-2)

but the `replaceState` do not work anymore apparently in angular7.

Has it been moved? how can I change the url like this :

if I am in www.website.com/mypage/

I would like to add parameters on user interaction obtaining the following

www.website.com/mypage/param1/param2 but without any reload or location change.

Comment: Hi! So I just checked the Angular docs and it still stated clearly the replaceState() method. Kindly check your code properly and align with what the docs describe: [link](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#replacestate)

Comment: If `Location.replaceState` method doesn't work you may use [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) object of browser `History.replaceState`.
Angular **Location** use **History** for this purpose

Comment: pass ``{skipLocationChange : true}``

Answer (score 0):

To change the URL without reloading the component associated to it we can use Query Params .

```
constructor (private router: Router,private route: ActivatedRoute)


this.router.navigate([],{
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams : {
        anyName: Value
      }
```

By  Using this logic we can pass anything in **anyName** to give the QueryParam a name and **Value** of our choice to show in URL